# No response when calling REST API through GEOROUTE

Tags: stata, here-api, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to calculate the travel distance between two pairs of lat long using the GEOROUTE package (version SJ22-1 dm0092_1) in Stata 13 and Here REST API. But every time I run the syntax I get the following error. Does it mean there's something wrong with my API authentication?
[Screenshot of the error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYKkg.jpg)

Comment: Probably, as the last line suggests that. But the first three lines seems to be more about setting up a secure connection. There is not enough information in the error message to be sure what the error is. Unless one is experiences with this specific API. Which I am not

Comment: Could you please share the complete request URL including APP ID. As per the error in last line of s/s there seems issue in your HERE credentials. Please check and respond.

Comment: Could you please share the complete request URL including APP ID. As per the error in last line of s/s there seems issue in your HERE credentials.

Comment: Dear User, Could you please confirm ,if you still facing the issue or we can mark this as answered.?