# Georoute and HERE

Tags: stata, here-api

I am trying to use the Stata package `georoute`, which uses HERE API keys to calculate the commuting time between two points. When I try to run the following code:

```
global apikey [THE KEY]
georoutei, herekey($apikey) startxy(Lon Lat) endxy(_CX _CY) tmode(pedestrian)
```

Stata says there is an error with my credentials. Several users have had this issue and no one seems to have found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72860448/no-response-when-calling-rest-api-through-georoute) nor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72860448/no-response-when-calling-rest-api-through-georoute?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C78.5960) nor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75889085/running-api-routing-in-stata-received-invalid-credentials-error/75950099?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C33.5916#75950099).

I suspect this could have to do with HERE Developer being migrated to HERE Platform. I have tried using REST keys from HERE Platform and I get that error. When trying to set up a project on HERE Developer I get redirected to HERE Platform. I have tried creating various keys on HERE Platform and on HERE Developer, registering for the Freemium account and including payment details and yet I am not able to use HERE developer, always get redirected to HERE Platform.

Comment: As you say, this is often asked but never answered. Have you tried contacting the authors of `georoute`? They are more likely than most Stata users to know what is going on. Also, the tag `here-api` is surely relevant. Many of these data download sites "stop working", as the developers change how to interact with them, with the not-so-surprising motive of trying to get you play serious money for their product.  I have no idea of whether that is the case here.

Comment: ... pay serious money...

Comment: Thank you Nick, I have already contacted the authors of georoute - who were not able to solve the issue; and the HERE platform, who have confirmed there are no issues with the credentials on their end. I am afraid if no one has the solution this might mean the package georoute is obsolete for now. If someone is thinking of fixing the bug please do and if it helps, I suspect it has to do with the migration from HERE developer to HERE platform. Thanks!